Booming Blade interaction with Pact of the Blade, Agonizing Blast and Repelling Blast
So I'm trying to work out a new build using the 2024 rules and want to check if I have the calculations correct. I know that the forced movement from the push won't trigger booming blade but if they try to move back into range it would trigger. I also know that you can no longer Action Surge to do this twice due to new rules.
The build is a Warlock/Fighter multiclass using the following class features

Warlock Invocation: Repelling blast (Booming Blade)
Warlock Invocation: Agonizing blast (Booming Blade)
Warlock Invocation: Pact of the Blade (Summoned Warhammer)
Fighter Weapon Mastery: Warhammer (Push)

This should let my attack be:
To hit = d20 + Proficiency + CHA
Damage on hit = (war hammer 1d8) + (CHA from Pact of Blade) + (CHA from Agonizing Blast) + (0-3 x 1d8s from Booming Blade)
Effect on hit = (pushed 10 ft by Push Weapon Mastery) + (pushed 10 ft by Repelling Blast) = 20 ft push away
Damage on character move = ( 1-4 x 1d8s from Booming Blade) + (CHA from Agonizing Blast)
What I'm not clear on is:

Is Agonizing Blast damage added to Booming Blade damage on move?
Is Charisma added twice on the hit damage correct? Can Agonizing Blast be taken with Booming Blade with the 2024 rules?
Both Repelling Blast and Weapon Mastery War Hammer have a push 10 feet effect, do these stack or would the 'Conditions Don't Stack' rule apply here?
Description for both Repelling Blast and Push mention 'you can push...' does this mean I could choose to push a target 0ft, 10ft or 20ft depending on the situation?


Welcome to Stack Exchange Roleplaying games form. You have a list of questions, each about a different aspect fo the character and each a rules question. For each of the bullet points above, (following the "what I'm not clear on is:") please ask as a seperate question. This will help other people searching for answers to any of thsoe questions find them easier than them all being on the same question.

First of all, the damage caused by weapon attacks in spells like Booming Blade or Green-Flame Blade is not considered spell's damage rolls, which is necessary for interacting with Agonizing Blast (emphasis mine):

Agonizing Blast. Choose one of your known Warlock cantrips that deals
damage. You can add your Charisma modifier to that spell's damage
rolls.

With this in mind:
Is Agonizing Blast damage added to Booming Blade damage on move?
Yes, the Eldritch Invocation should apply to the spell's damage rolls for the thunder damage (both the primary and secondary thunder, if applicable at higher levels) considering the explanation provided above.
Is Charisma added twice on the hit damage correct?
Not always, depending on your level.
Before level 5, Charisma should be added only once to the weapon's damage due to the Pact of the Blade, and only once to the thunder damage when the enemy moves due to Agonizing Blast.
At higher levels (5+), Agonizing Blast should interact with Booming Blade twice: Charisma should be added to the target on a hit (primary thunder) and also added to the damage when the target moves (secondary thunder).
Can Agonizing Blast be taken with Booming Blade with the 2024 rules?
Yes, the 2024 Player's Handbook is backwards compatible. Booming Blade is not included in the 2024 PHB, so we need to use the version from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything. Older spells like Booming Blade or Green-Flame Blade can be played as-is without any conversion. The only change is that you must use the Magic action to cast them.
Both Repelling Blast and Weapon Mastery War Hammer have a push 10 feet effect, do these stack or would the 'Conditions Don't Stack' rule apply here?
They come from different sources with different names, so they should stack.
The 2024 DMG is not available yet, but even the current rule from the 2014 DMG doesn't prohibit this specific stacking:

Combining Game Effects
Different game features can affect a target at
the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name,
only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the
durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited
by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t
increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game
features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster
abilities, and magic items. See the related rule in the “Combining
Magical Effects” section of chapter 10 in the Player’s Handbook.

Description for both Repelling Blast and Push mention 'you can push...' does this mean I could choose to push a target 0ft, 10ft or 20ft depending on the situation?
Yes, you can choose whether to use those benefits or not. This is supported by the word can in the descriptions.

If booming blade after level 5 does thunder damage on hit, and then later on move, is that 2 damage rolls this getting agonising blast twice? And cha would be added twice on hit because one time is weapon damage, and one time is agonising blast? Then if it gets added again later this would end up applying cha damage 3 times? I think those questions are part of what the OP was wanting clarity on

@SeriousBri Totally agree. Please let me know if those cases are now covered.

Could you compile examples of how it all works, for level 4 and level 5 character?

Looks good to me now

For a couple of these subquestions you just said “yes” without explaining or justifying your answer, which someone who knew absolutely nothing about the game could do too. I’ve downvoted for unsupported assertions.

@ThomasMarkov I added extra explanations for some of the questions. I'm not sure if they were the ones you were referring to. Please let me know if you feel the information is still insufficient.

@Mołot I've just realized the original question is blocked because it needs to be more focused. So, I'll wait and see if it's worth continuing with further edits to my answer. Thanks for your suggestion!
